# Transform array elements to parent and children

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, nested-lists

Want to transform array from single layer to nested.

So if the element has field **parentId="3"** it must be added to **children** field of that element who has **id="3"**

For example **"Late"** must be a children of **"Coffee"**, and **"Nested Late"** must be a children of **"Late"**.

Example:

*input data:*

```
const data = [
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Coffee",
      parentId: null,
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Late",
      parentId: "2",
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      name: "Nested Late",
      parentId: "3",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Books",
      parentId: null,
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      name: "Nested Book",
      parentId: "4",
    }
  ];
```

*output:*

```
const result = [
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Coffee",
    parentId: null,
    children: [
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Late",
        parentId: "2",
        children: [
          {
            id: "6",
            name: "Nested Late",
            parentId: "3",
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Books",
    parentId: null,
    children: [
      {
        id: "5",
        name: "Nested Book",
        parentId: "4",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: what is the specific problem, you face?

Comment: cause I didn't know the count of nested layers I can't transform it correctly.